# Displaying a unicode text in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, internationalization, unicode-string

My App displays English, Japanese and Chinese characters on a TextBox and a LinkLabel.
Currently, I check if there are unicode characters and change the font to MS Mincho or else leave it in Tahoma.

Now MS Mincho displays Japanese properly, but for Chinese I have to use Sim Sun. How can I distinguish between the two?

How can I ensure that unicode text are displayed properly regardless of the font/language?

Comment: Just used @shahkalpesh's answer for my BingDownloader project...
http://bing.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have unicode characters for each of the text, using a font that supports unicode should cover it properly for you (e.g. Arial Unicode MS).

Comment: This is perfect. I was tweaking around like what @dtb said. But this ArialUnicode font is not only good looking, but serves the purpose well... :D

Comment: It should be noted that Arial Unicode MS must be licensed before you can redistribute it.

Comment: @epotter: doesn't Arial Unicode MS come by default with .NET / Win7 /WinXP for end users?

Comment: Yes, it comes with the OS. And one doesn't need to distribute it as such. Experts in copyright matters can provide guidance on this.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I quote [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5761948/848344): "The better one is "Arial Unicode MS", but it may be absent on OS earlier than Vista without MS Office installed."

Comment: @DanW, that may be true. At the time I made the comment, I was supporting some earlier OSs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't ensure that unicode text is displayed properly regardless of the font and language, because **there is no single font that can render all possible unicode characters**.  You have to select a font that can display the unicode characters that you need to render.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I think the question is: How do you detect the language so you can choose the right font, given that a string only contains characters of one language?

Answer (score 2):

All strings in C# are Unicode. The English (Latin), Japanese and Chinese code points are just located in different code point ranges.

I think you have two options:

- Find a Unicode font that contains characters for all code points in all three language.
- Try to guess the language and choose a font that contains the characters for the code points in that language.

For option 2 you can look at the [Unicode charts](http://unicode.org/charts/) to find out where the different code points are and expand your algorithm to guess the language.

Example for [Hiragana](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3040.pdf):

```
bool IsHiragana(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= '\u3040') && (ch <= '\u309f');
}

bool IsHiragana(string s)
{
    return s.Count(IsHiragana) > 0;
}
```

Comment: @dtb: I don't think OP wants to distinguish between Japanese and Chinese etc (atleast that is not what is said). OP says "How can I ensure that unicode text are displayed properly regardless of the font/language?"

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Right, but there's no perfect answer to this. Not all fonts contain characters for all Unicode code points, so it's not possible to display arbitrary Unicode strings regardless of font.

Comment: @dtb: You are right as well. If I am right, Arial Unicode MS has the coverage for scripts OP wants.