# Is it not possible to Paste Chinese Characters on Windows Form Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, textbox, cjk

I am working on a WinForm App and I have a text box where I am pasting texts from Google Translator. I have got positive results with several Sematic and Indo Languages but Chinese characters appear as Boxes.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: It's because your default Windows font - probably Microsft Sans Serif - doesn't have those characters. You can change the font that the text box is using to something else e.g. Arial Unicode (if you have Office) or one of the Chinese-specific fonts but I don't know a way to do this per character or intelligently based on content. Assuming your app is Unicode then the characters will still be pasted correctly, by the way, even if they're not displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I am using Microsfot Sans Serif. Do you recommend using Arial Unicode? Will it resolve a lot of the issues?

Comment: I don't know - I guess it's probably better to use the default font alone if you can (and Chinese users will already be using a font that supports their characters - mingliu?). Arial Unicode is shipped with Office not Windows though so only people with Office installed will have it so it's probably not the best choice, depending on who you're deploying to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use appropriate Unicode font which supports CJK encodings. The better one is "Arial Unicode MS", but it may be absent on
OS earlier than Vista without MS Office installed. In this case you may use another font like "NSimSun".

```
string arialUnicodeFontFace = "Arial Unicode MS";
Font unicodeFont = new Font(arialUnicodeFontFace, fontSize);
if (unicodeFont.Name != arialUnicodeFontFace)
    unicodeFont = new Font("NSimSun", fontSize);

yourTextBox.Font = unicodeFont;
```

You may also look at the list of all supported CJK fonts in different versions of Windows:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts

Comment: "Arial Unicode MS" appears not to be able in Vista (or Win7 for that matter) by default - there too, you need some Office product such as Word or Excel. See: http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081