# Allow typing of non English Characters in text box

Tags: vb.net, globalization

In VB.NET, I want to allow typing of non English Characters (For example, Russian, Turkish) in text box. How can I achieve this? Please let me know.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646548/is-it-not-possible-to-paste-chinese-characters-on-windows-form-text-box

Comment: Do nothing.  If you want to test it then add a keyboard layout or copy/paste from a site like google.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe richtextbox allows for that.  You're talking about accents and umlauts right?

If so, I'm pretty sure if you just resize your richtextbox down to the size of your textbox then you'll be alright.

If that doesn't work try importing a language pack resource.  Use MSDN for specific ones.

Hope that helped