# RichBox or TXTbox not showing UTF-8 characters

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

i am making a program that converts all the bytes of a file to plain text (Encoded in UTF-8) , the problem appears when i want to display the text on a RichBox or a Textbox, it only shows/writes a few characters or none of them . This problem doesn't emerge when the file only contains unicode simple characters (Latin alphabet) and numbers

This is my code:

```
richTextBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath));
```

Why this is happening? , it's a bug in VB or is my fault? Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371077/displaying-a-unicode-text-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I was trying to say that the characters are not even being written. This is not the typical problem of the missing characters with the empty rectangles like this : 

Comment: (You could simplify to `richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath, Encoding.UTF8);`) Please show more of your code. Divide and conquer by putting the string in a String variable and analyzing that first. Then, does richTextBox1.Multiline equal true?

Comment: @TomBlodget  byte[] FileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                        string PlainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FileBytes);         This is all my code indeed ( I'm only testing , not making something very serious). I debugged this code by putting breakdowns and i found that the variable "PlainText" actually it has all the UTF-8 characters within  but when i want to display it into a richtext it only shows some characters :(

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try this C# solution that I'm using currently:

```
byte[] bytes = { 130, 200, 234, 23 }; // A byte array contains non-ASCII (or non-readable) characters

string s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // ���
byte[] decBytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s1);  // decBytes1.Length == 10 !!
// decBytes1 not same as bytes
// Using UTF-8 or other Encoding object will get similar results

string s2 = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);   // 82-C8-EA-17
String[] tempAry = s2.Split('-');
byte[] decBytes2 = new byte[tempAry.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < tempAry.Length; i++)
    decBytes2[i] = Convert.ToByte(tempAry[i], 16);
// decBytes2 same as bytes

string s3 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);  // gsjqFw==
byte[] decByte3 = Convert.FromBase64String(s3);
// decByte3 same as bytes

string s4 = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes);    // gsjqFw2
byte[] decBytes4 = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(s4);
// decBytes4 same as bytes
```

Just adjust the syntax to VB.NET, it's fairly simple...